# Disabling hotlinking images hinders Facebook from showing images

Tags: wordpress, facebook, cpanel

I disabled hotlinking via CPanel, and added my own website,  plus my CDN, www.facebook.com, facebook.com to the exceptions list for both https and http protocols.

However, when I use the Facebook debugger https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug, it often (not always) removes the featured image and simply shows a grey box where the image should be.  It also displays the message the image

> "could not be processed as an image because it has an invalid content
>   type".

The debugger lists this message for all images on the page.  In most cases, the images are either jpg or png files.

If I turn off hotlink protection, the message goes away and the images return.

Is there another URL I should be using for FB images in my hotlink exceptions list?

Comment: Do you allow an _empty_ `Referer`? If you check these requests in your server's access log then that should tell you precisely what you need to add to your exceptions list.

Comment: Thanks @MrWhite.  I don't see anything particularly alarming in my log file, but I also don't see any way in CPanel to allow for blank referers.  I guess I'll have to do this via .htaccess.  Thank you.